# Count the first record in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, count

I have a table like this (after i user filter)

```
ID    user_id      action_type    created_date
1       123            3           27/1/2022
2       123            3           30/1/2022
3       123            3           08/03/2022
4       123            3           08/03/2022
```

then i have this query

```
select date_trunc('week', created_date::timestamptz) as "Week"
      ,count(distinct user_id) filter (where action_type = 3) as "linkbank"
From action_logs
Where action_type = 3 and user_id = '123'
Group by "Week"
```

And the result of query belike this

```
Week           linkbank
24/01/2022         1
07/03/2022         1
```

**So if i have to count the first time the client linkbank, what i should change in my query?**

For example if i change the query with `user_id =123`, i want the result will take the first row only

I will try everything you comment.

Tks.

Comment: You want the first row ordered by what ?

Comment: I mean I want the result will take the first time client link bank. 

For example, a client has 2 times link bank. The first time on 24/01 , the second on 07/03. So i only need take result is the first time. Is there any chance to do it.

Comment: Does this work only for one selected user ? What if you don't add user_id condition ?

Comment: I already try `Where If(action_type = 3 then MIN(created_date) End If)` but it failed
Do you any query recommend for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it for only one `user_id`

```
select date_trunc('week', created_date::timestamptz) as "Week"
      ,count(distinct user_id) filter (where action_type = 3) as "linkbank"
From action_logs
Where action_type = 3 and user_id = 123
Group by "Week"
order by "Week"
limit 1;
```

If you want it for all users

```
with l as (
  select row_number() over (partition by user_id order by user_id, date_trunc('week', created_date::timestamptz)) as rn,user_id, date_trunc('week', created_date::timestamptz) as "Week"
        ,count(distinct user_id) filter (where action_type = 3) as "linkbank"
  From action_logs
  Where action_type = 3
  Group by user_id,"Week"
)
select * from l where rn = 1
```

[Results here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cLR5f5ZBhEsJkMErLRiwz3/0)

Comment: Is there any chance to group by "Week" only, if i want it for all users.

Comment: I try this but it say missing FROM-clause entry for table "test" 

`Select date_trunc('week', Test.Week::timestamptz) as "Week"
      , Count(Test.user_id)
From 
    (with l as (
    select row_number() over (partition by user_id order by user_id, date_trunc('week', created_date::timestamptz)) as rn,user_id, date_trunc('week', created_date::timestamptz) as "Week"
        ,count(distinct user_id) filter (where action_type = 3) as "linkbank"
    From action_logs
    Where action_type = 3
    Group by user_id,"Week"
    )
    select * from l where rn = 1) as "Test"
Group by 1`

Comment: also, your first answer seem to be take the first row. I put out condition `User_id = 123` and it take only first row, not the first time.

Comment: if you don't add `user_id` condition, the first query will return the first record ordered by date whatever the user_id is. The second will return the first record by user_id. Maybe i misunderstood what you want to do ?

Comment: oh, the second is what I need, but it seems to be wrong sth in the query when I try to sub-query. I will try it again. Anyway, thank you for your help.